# In an enterprise Java application where does SQL reside?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Let's say there is a web server build on Spark Java with a Postgres backend. There is a Database Connection Pool that allows different Services or Controllers to use a connection and query the database. My question is, where is the SQL stored?

Are they inline:

```
String sql = "Select * From Users;"
```

Are queries built in a factory that spits back a string:

```
String sql = SqlFactory.createQuery(SQL_ENUM.TYPE, params);
```

Are all queries stored within the Database Server and called as a stored procedure?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It depends how you write it. All three variants which you mentioned are possible.

Comment: They are all possible. I should have asked for potential drawbacks to each method. It seems like java code could quickly be overrun but inline strings but then strictly using stored procedures could hinder flexibility.

Comment: Any of the above, and more possibilities besides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's up to the system designers. There's no one right answer, and there are places you didn't mention like configuration files (XML, etc.). Usually there is a mix of multiple sources.

It's a good idea to use `PreparedStatement` when writing JDBC queries, for security and type safety. But besides JDBC, there is JPA, among other libraries that use SQL under the hood.

As a rule of thumb, stored procedures in the DBMS hold SQL related to maintenance of the DB structures as such. Domain logic for persistence tends to reside in application and middleware code.

Some systems establish data operations declaratively, using annotations.

So the answer, as is common in engineering, is, "It depends."

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought about XML and assume queries are loaded as resources? Thank you for the "rule" about stored procedures. I'll have to look up using annotations for data operations. Thank You.

Comment: For stored procedures and functions, try the `CallableStatement`.